# How to stop GridView edit button from changing after editing is done?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

### Edit

I've arrived at a solution which makes any answer on this question irrelevant to my current application of the GridView, however, if you can provide a helpful answer, please do so as others may have the same problem and might come here looking for a solution.

My solution was to use CommandFields in my GridView and then reacting to particular events:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="View/Edit" />
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="true" />
```

In my backend code:

```
protected void gvThings_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    // Load data based on the selected row's data key
    // and present an edit form prepopulated with the data.
}

protected void gvThings_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    // Select and delete data based on the selected row's data key.
}
```

### Original Question

I'm using `RowEditing` on my GridView to edit the data.

When you click on a row's Edit button, the page changes to show you a form where you can edit and save the changes after which the page reverts back to reload the list and display the data to the user.

The problem is that when the view changes back to the list, there's Update / Cancel links on the record like the GridView thinks its still editing.

Here's my code:

```
protected void gvSuppliers_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        // Make a note of the identifier for the row
        // where it can be accessed later
        ViewState.Add("SupplierId", (Guid)gvSuppliers.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value);
        var supplierId = (Guid)ViewState["SupplierId"];

        // Get the data and load the entity
        var supplier = db.Suppliers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SupplierId == supplierId);

        txtEditName.Text = supplier.Name;

        mvSuppliers.ActiveViewIndex = mvSuppliers.Views.IndexOf(vEdit); // go to edit form
    }
}

protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEditName.Text))
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            // Get the identifier again and update the entity
            var supplierId = (Guid)ViewState["SupplierId"];
            var supplier = db.Suppliers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SupplierId == supplierId);

            if (supplier != null)
            {
                supplier.Name = txtEditName.Text;
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Reload the GridView's data and show it on the page again
                LoadSuppliers();
                mvSuppliers.ActiveViewIndex = mvSuppliers.Views.IndexOf(vList); // go back to the list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the `EditIndex` to `-1` and rebind the GridView.

Comment: You can set `btnEdit` Visibility to `Hidden` after editing.